# Finite population correction for calculating margin of error

Tags: standard-error, survey, finite-population

Let's say that I have a population of 10000, and I have a sample of 300 that have responded to an online survey. Of 10000 invitations, 300 hundred have replied. Would I be able to use the finite population correction for margin of error?

Population: 10000
Sample: 300
Response: 3%

Comment: if you have a representative sample why do you need corrections?

Comment: It sounds like you have an *intended sample size* of 10000 and a 97% non-response rate.  Your "population" is probably much, much greater than 10000.

Comment: Perhaps my understanding of "population" is misconstrued. Essentially, I'm trying to estimate the margin of error associated with a survey I recently ran on the clients of a company. What I'd like to be able to say is something like. "X% Clients of company Y agree that Z, with a margin of error of A."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a 3% response rate, it is highly likely that self-selection has made this a biased sample.  whuber has also pointed out that 10000 may not be the whole population.

If the population was 10000 and if you had a random sample of 300 then you could make a finite population correction.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error_%28statistics%29#Correction_for_finite_population) suggests a multiplicative factor for the standard error of $$\sqrt{\dfrac{N-n}{N-1}}$$ which with $N=10000$ and $n=300$ is about $0.985$, not something that is going to make a lot of difference.

Comment: Yes, perhaps my terminology is incorrect and certainly self-selection is a problem in all online research. However, 10k is truely the universe for this population. So how do I calculate MoE? Or can I?

Comment: The Wikipedia article also says that the FPC is intended for use when the sample size is greater than 5% of the population. For example, if your sample is 25%, the FPC is .8703, which could make more of a difference

Comment: Which formula for M of E is less important than whether to report one.  There is a short discussion at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7134/accommodating-entrenched-views-of-p-values that is relevant to this.  Lots and lots of people report, for self-selected samples, inferential statistics derived from methods intended only for random samples.  But as a reflective, informed person, you'll know that to do so is unsound and that margins of error will not have their nominal limits.  At the post linked above I described a sort of workaround to this, which was met with mixed reviews.