# Mann-Whitney U Test Analysis Help

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

Good day! I'm totally new to SPSS (and the test as well, but after some research I've finally demystified a bit about Mann-Whitney and how to do the test in SPSS. The only problem I'm currently facing is the analysis) And so in this snippet, I want to discover how the researcher came up with this analysis:

[image: Valid XHTML].

How was he able to come up with a conclusion that there is no significant difference between the examination marks? What specific data in the table made him conclude that? What variables did he look at? If I were to use a Mann-Whitney test and have to interpret the results, where will I look at? What are the factors do I have to consider? Any help would be very much appreciated. :)

Also, what's the purpose of the Z and Wilcoxon W?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Asymp. Sig. (2-tailed)" refers to a two-tailed *p* value for the Mann–Whitney test, which indicates the significance of its comparison of ranks for the two groups of gamers. Since *p* > .1, his conclusion that these results are insignificant is probably not going to attract much debate. BTW, [an exact *p* value is also calculable for these tests, but may take longer with somewhat large samples](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/19565-Asymptotic-vs-Exact) such as this.

As for the meaning of *Z* and the Wilcoxon *W*, I think [another answer of mine](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/87404/32036) has the info you want:

> The [Wilcoxon signed-rank test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) is appropriate for paired samples, whereas the Mann–Whitney test assumes independent samples. However, according to [Field <sup>(2000)</sup>](http://www.statisticshell.com/docs/nonparametric.pdf), the Wilcoxon *W* in your SPSS output is "a different
>   version of this statistic, which can be converted into a Z score and can, therefore, be compared against critical values of the normal distribution." That explains your *z* score too then! FYI, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann-Whitney_U_test#Normal_approximation) adds that, for large samples, *U* is approximately normally distributed.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>**Reference**
>
>   Field, A. (2000). 3.1. Mann-Whitney test. *Research Methods 1: SPSS for Windows part 3: Nonparametric tests.* Retrieved from http://www.statisticshell.com/docs/nonparametric.pdf.</sup>

His sample is fairly large, and the *p* value should be the same for all test statistics if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I thought the analysis has something to do with the Z. (I got carried away with the negative sign because my correlation test a while ago yielded a negative value). **Thank you** :D

Comment: +1 Field - as so often - is sort of right, but misleading. All of the usual versions of the Wilcoxon rank sum statistics are asymptotically normal and "can be converted to a Z score".